# AVPlayer play button is not playing video when tap gesture is on player

Tags: swift, swiftui, avplayer

I'm working on a workaround to having my AVPlayer appear fullscreen. Currently it will automatically go fullscreen and present the video if the user clicks anywhere but the play button.

My issue right now is when the user individually just clicks on the play button, the video doesn't play. Is there a way I can set each buttons action as the same as they were before (play button plays, rewind rewinds, etc) and still keep my .sheet behavior?

```
struct Profile_LicksFullDisplay: View {


    private func isTapOnPlayButton(tapLocation: CGPoint, videoPlayerFrame: CGRect) -> Bool {
        // Adjust the play button's position based on the videoPlayerFrame
        let playButtonCenter = CGPoint(x: videoPlayerFrame.midX, y: videoPlayerFrame.midY)

        // Calculate the origin of the play button frame based on the center
        let playButtonFrame = CGRect(
            x: playButtonCenter.x - (50 / 2),   // Adjust for half of the button width
            y: playButtonCenter.y - (50 / 2),   // Adjust for half of the button height
            width: 50,
            height: 50
        )

        // Now, check if the tap is within the play button frame
        return playButtonFrame.contains(tapLocation)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // ...

            if let videoURL = videoURL {
                VideoPlayerView(player: AVPlayer(url: videoURL))
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
                    .onTapGesture { gesture in
                        // Get the video player view frame
                        if let playerView = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.view {
                            let videoPlayerFrame = playerView.frame

                            // Check if the tap was on the play button
                            if !isTapOnPlayButton(tapLocation: gesture.location(in: playerView), videoPlayerFrame: videoPlayerFrame) {
                                showingDetail = true
                                UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(
                                    UIViewController(), animated: false, completion: nil
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
            } else {
                Text("Video URL is missing")
            }

            // ...
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingDetail) {
            VideoPlayerView(player: AVPlayer(url: videoURL!))
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}

struct VideoPlayerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var player: AVPlayer

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player
        controller.showsPlaybackControls = true
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {}

    class Coordinator: NSObject, AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate {
        var parent: VideoPlayerView

        init(parent: VideoPlayerView) {
            self.parent = parent
            super.init()
        }

        func playerViewController(
            _ playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController,
            willBeginFullScreenPresentationWithAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator
        ) {
            // Handle full-screen presentation
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried pressing the `play` button for a bit longer than normal, that is, not just a tap.